# Is private language argument against absolute idealism?

Tags: wittgenstein, idealism, realism, private-language

Wittgenstein famously proposed that private language is an incoherent notion. Does this refute some version of idealism which claims that the reality is totally mind-dependent ?

For me an argument goes as follows :

1- private language is impossible.

2- For the mentioned idealist, words of the language refer to some private thoughts or feelings.

3-so, absolute idealism is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you mean something like subjective idealism or solipsism (Wittgenstein was explicitly targeting the latter). It would not apply to the Mind of [absolute idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_idealism) that creates reality itself.